# Netsuite Advanced PDF

Tags: html, pdf, freemarker, netsuite, bfo

I am trying to create a print out for Bill of Materials using Advanced PDF in Netsuite. I am using source code. How can I changed the orientation of my print out from portrait to landscape? I know that when using WYSWYG, I can just simply choose the orientation in the Template Setup but that option is not available when using Source Code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set the page size with the `size` attribute on the `<body>` tag.

```
<body size="A4-landscape">
```

or

```
<body size="letter-landscape">
```

[Link to documentation](http://bfo.com/products/report/docs/tags/atts/size.html)